# Ubuntu shuts down unexpectedly, Every night

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, cron

I know this sounds weird but unfortunately it's real. I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on Dell Inspiron N5150 Laptop with intel i7 CPU and nvidia GeForce GPU.

Every night between 9:30 pm and 11 pm the system shuts down unexpectedly as if I clicked the shut down button myself (I have experienced this many nights, for like three months). And when I start the computer again, there's no error or message of any kind on system startup.

When I'm running Ubuntu on daytime I don't have this problem at all, even if it spends all the day running (it just shuts down on night). I did:

```
sudo crontab -u fourat -l # where fourat is my main user
sudo crontab -u root -l
```

but I get no crontab for

UPDATE: `ps aux` output: http://pastebin.com/ViN23V4K

Please help.

Comment: Try `ps aux | grep shut!` around that time.  Maybe there's a process running for that

Comment: In fact,  you might want to explore the whole output of ps. If you add that to the question maybe it can help us  identify what's causing it

Comment: @Serg http://pastebin.com/ViN23V4K I also tried to change the system time to times where this problem used to happen but it didn't shut down. I'm starting to think that I have a RAT in my system :D

Comment: If it happens when you aren't connected to interwebz , it's not a RAT ;)

Comment: Is there a way that I can log everything that the system executes so the next time it happens I can know exactly which program caused it ?

Comment: Didn't see anything interesting in the output of ps , except for /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon , but ibus is input method daemon , so it couldn't have been it. Um .  . . I don't know.  You could check /var/log folder.  There's syslog and dmesg logs.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131993/what-audit-log-files-are-created-in-linux-to-track-a-users-activities

Comment: dmesg is not timestamped I didn't get where to look exactly and syslog has too many lines around the time it happened this night (22:54) so is there any particular lines I should look for ? Thank you for your help @Serg

Comment: I don't particularly know.  Post the syslog portion around that time and I'll take a look. Sorry I cannot be more helpful at this point

Comment: Here's the syslog: http://pastebin.com/g45fbmBL There is a 3 minutes gap between 22:47 and 22:50 and between 22:59 and 23:02 (I thins this is where the system finished startup)